# How to unit test nested HTTP Calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following function I'm trying to unit test:

```
async fetchGreatHouseByName(name: string) {
  const [house] = await this.httpGetHouseByName(name);
  const currentLord = house.currentLord ? house.currentLord : '957';
  const result: any = await this.httpGetLord(currentLord);
  const character = Characters.default.find(char => char.characterName === result.name);
  return {...house, character};
}
```

Inside of this function are multiple HTTP GET calls. I know how to test them, **but how do I handle nested HTTP Calls**, which each is a Promise.

What I got:

```
it('should get house from http', done => {
  const httpMock: HttpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);

  const mockResponse = {
    name: 'House One',
    currentLord: 'Some Lord'
  };

  service.fetchGreatHouseByName('House One').then((house: House) => {
    expect(house).toBeTruthy();
    console.log(house);
  });

  const mockRequest = httpMock.expectOne(
    'https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses?name=House%20Lannister%20of%20Casterly%20Rock'
  );

  mockRequest.flush(mockResponse);

});
```

So `httpGetHouseByName` typically returns something like `mockRequest`. And `httpGetLord` and object containing `name` among other properties. Do I need one more mock for this HTTP call and if so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think calling the function should put two HTTP calls in queue. Try flushing both calls in series and putting your assertions in the `.then` block.

```
it('should get house from http', done => {
  const httpMock: HttpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);

  const mockResponse = {
    name: 'House One',
    currentLord: 'Some Lord'
  };

  service.fetchGreatHouseByName('House One').then((house: House) => {
    expect(house).toBeTruthy();
    console.log(house);
    // your other assertions here
  });

  const mockRequest = httpMock.expectOne(
    'https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses?name=House%20Lannister%20of%20Casterly%20Rock'
  );

  mockRequest.flush(mockResponse);

  const response = {
     // mock response of httpGetLord here
    };
  const request = httpMock.expectOne(/* url of httpGetLord*/);
  request.flush(response);
});
```